# How can I delete a folder named '.' from SVN?

Tags: windows, svn, tortoise-svn

I'm attempting to check out a directory from my company's SVN repo using TortoiseSVN on Windows 10. Unfortunately, somebody at some point managed to check in a folder called `.` (a period/fullstop) which is causing the checkout to fail with the message: `'.' is not valid as filename in directory 'C:\path\to\my\checkout'`.

The directory is partially checked out -- about half of its contents are present on my local. However the '.' folder is not. An SVN update command via TortoiseSVN also fails with the same error message. Similarly, if I use `svn up` from the commandline, it also fails:

```
C:\path\to\my\checkout>svn up
Updating '.':
svn: E155000: '.' is not valid as filename in directory 'C:\path\to\my\checkout'
```

I would like to delete this invalid folder but I can't figure out how since I am unable to download it. How can I do so? (I have no access to the VM that hosts the company SVN.) Alternatively, how can I finish checking out the rest of this directory?

Comment: do you have access to the data from a linux/mac computer? Windows doesn't like that folder name, so maybe using something other than Windows will let you do what you need to do.

Comment: @SirAdelaide Linux won't like that name either :/

Comment: I ran into this problem, and for me the error was misleading.  Someone had accidentally committed a folder named `C:`.  After removing that folder, all was well.